# findViewbyId in custom adapter returns null

Tags: android-adapter

I am trying to retrieve a textView in a custom Adapter but it is returning null for some reason. Can you guys explain why?  am new to Android and am stuck here. I am also attaching the view the adapter is connecting to, its called profile_listitem.xml and contains the textView I want.

Thank you

AdapterProfile.xml

```
public AdapterProfiles(Context context,ArrayList<Profile> profilesArray)
{
    super(context, R.layout.profile_listitem, profilesArray);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Profile p= getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.profile_listitem , parent, false);
    }
    TextView textAppName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewApp);
    ToggleButton appStatus =(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleAppStatus);

    if(convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewApp)==null)
        Log.d("Profile","Profile is  null");

    textAppName.setText(p.getName());
    appStatus.setChecked(p.isActive());

    return convertView;
}
```

profile_listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/textViewAppName"/>
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:id="@+id/toggleAppStatus"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have used

> R.id.textViewApp

instead of what you defined in the xml file i.e.

> R.id.textViewAppName

TextView textAppName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById('R.id.textViewApp');